# How to use "e.g."

Tags: word-usage, writing-style

I usually write "e.g." when I give an example. But, I just wonder if I have to add comma after e.g. because Some published papers indicate "(e.g.~~~)", and others said "(e.g.,~~~)".

In addition, are parentheses necessary or optional?

Comment: I am not sure about the comma, because e.g. means example gracia (for example) and you do not put a comma after  "for example", but the parenthesis are totally optional.

Comment: Exempli gratia, actually.  I think the comma is usually used; you could omit it if the example is just one word. Parentheses are not necessary.